# systemd Before and After definition?

Tags: systemd

The definition given in the man for systemd unit is a bit sparse:
https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html

"If a unit foo.service contains a setting `Before=bar.service` and both units are being started, bar.service's **start-up is delayed until foo.service is started up**."

I couldn't find any conclusive explanation on what 'started up' means. Is this just the call from systemd to the service to start up. Or does systemd wait for the service to enter a specific state after which it is considered to be up? Can I read details on how this works anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before being active, service is in activating mode. systemd waits for the service to fully enter in active mode. Only after that it calls dependent service to start.